# How do I configure Xamarin.iOS build step in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to configure Visual Studio Team Services to build a Xamarin.Forms project and build the project.  But I cannot get it queue a build on a hosted agent pool.  I am using the following build steps:

[Build Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzusN.png)

I click on Queue Build.

I receive the following error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCCHn.png)

It appears as though I am missing a critical step.  What did I forget to configure?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building "Xamarin.iOS" project requires an On-premises XPlat agent with Xamarin installed.
[image]

Deploying one according to the steps here: [OSX Agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/startosx.md) and then following the configuration here: [Define your Xamarin.iOS build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin#define-your-xamarin-ios-build).